# update sequelize boolean Value

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js

how can I change a boolean value?

I do this: `await Model.update({[reply.match[1]: reply.match[2] == 'off'});`
`reply.match[2] - off`
But it stopped working for me. This is ridiculous. What can I do?
error not

because true = false and vice versa. But it stopped working

`regular: /^status:(member|admin):(off|on):(\d+)$/`

full code:

```
const checkstatus = await Model.findOne({ where: { id: reply.match[3] } });
await checkstatus.update({[reply.match[1]]: reply.match[2] == 'off'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a typo in there? There seems to be an extra `[` that's not closed.

```
await checkstatus.update({reply.match[1]: reply.match[2] == 'off'})
```

Apart from that, based on the code, it looks like you're trying to set the property based on whether reply.match[2] is equal to 'off'.

That'll set the property to true if 'off' is matched, and false otherwise.

Is that the intended behavious? If not, then:

```
await checkstatus.update({ [reply.match[1]]: reply.match[2] === 'on' });
```

If that is the intended behaviour, do you mind posting the previous code that worked, so we can compare?

Comment: I forgot to close in the example. The question is still open

Comment: It still doesn't work. `{ member: false }` the situation is still the same

Comment: In that case, do you mind posting a console.log for matches 1, 2, & 3, and also the string you're testing?

Comment: `member off 1` <- reply.match

Comment: If you can do a minimum repro and post to codepen or other, happy to have a quick look at it?